# MySQL - Insert changes from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, insert

I have a simplified table:

```
id     date     color
----------------------
1   2012-01-01  black
2   2012-01-02  red
3   2012-01-03  red
4   2012-01-04  red
5   2012-01-05  green
```

And now I need to insert a color change from this table into new one:

```
   date     before   now
----------------------------
2012-01-02  black    red
2012-01-04  red      green
```

Can someone tell me how, please?

Comment: Is this homework? If it is, you should mark it as such. Also, what have you tried so far and how hasn't it worked?

Comment: the date on output is ambiguous, which date it is referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare second row to previous row:

```
SELECT cur.date, prev.color "before", cur.color now
FROM tbl cur
LEFT JOIN tbl prev ON cur.id = prev.id + 1
WHERE cur.id > 1 -- start detecting changes from second row
     AND prev.color <> cur.color
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c146/1

**EDIT**

Works even in non-contiguous data. Query could be more succint if there's CTE functionality in MySQL

```
create table tbl
(
  id int, 
  date date,
  color text
);


insert into tbl(id,date,color)
select 1,'2012-1-1','black' union
select 2,'2012-1-3','red' union
select 3,'2012-1-7','red' union
select 4,'2012-1-15','red' union
select 5,'2012-1-21','green' ;


set @rx = 0;
set @ry = 0;


select cur.date, prev.color as "before", cur.color as "now"

from (select *, @ry := @ry + 1 as series from tbl order by date) as cur 
left join (select *, @rx := @rx + 1 as series from tbl order by date) as prev
on cur.series = prev.series + 1

where cur.series > 1
and prev.color <> cur.color
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9443/2

Comment: Oh, but if row with id=4 will not exist, your code will not work anymore

Comment: I have a ready answer for that if MySQL supported CTE. Postgresql, Oracle, SQL Server do. I'll check how to simulate one in MySQL

Comment: I modify the answer, even if the id is non-contiguous the code will still work. Check the edit

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First, rename the `color` column -> `before`, then add the `now` column (`default null` if possible), then update the `now` column as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, stored procedures are what you need.

[Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)